# Why is the System process using 40-60% of CPU power all the time?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, kernel

**TL;DR:**

- ACPI.sys is constantly using lots of CPU power.
- Virus and malware scans all come back clean
- Drivers are up to date (GPU, Chipset, USB devices)

*Possibly important info:*

- This install of Win7 is on a SSD, which I had to install as a secondary boot through my primary OS (Vista). This was because my lame BIOS wouldn't let me boot from a disk or USB stick, so I need the old C:/ drive in there with Vista on it to be able to boot into Win7.
- My virtual memory is all on the SSD drive (I know this is bad for the drive but I wanted to improve performance and don't care if it dies in a few years)

---

My Windows 7 system is currently suffering from terrible performance issues. Looking at the processes in task manager shows that `System (NT Kernel & System)` process is using around 40-60% of the CPU all of the time.

A [blog post](http://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-7/fix-nt-kernel-system-process-cpu-usage-in-windows-7/) I found has suggested that this is often due to a driver issue, such as a USB device or graphics driver, so I did a stackwalk using xperf (`xperf -on latency -stackwalk profile`) and checked the output file in Windows Performance Analyzer and **it seems that `ACPI.sys` is causing the issue:**

[image: Inspecting the System process in Windows Performance Analyzer]

This is what I get when I expand the stack for ACPI.sys:

[image: I have no idea what this means]

[Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540493%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says:

> The Windows ACPI driver, Acpi.sys, is an inbox component of the Windows operating system. The responsibilities of Acpi.sys include support for power management and Plug and Play (PnP) device enumeration.

[Another user fixed a similar problem by updating their BIOS](https://superuser.com/questions/577008/system-acpi-sys-is-always-using-about-15-20-of-my-cpu?lq=1), but my BIOS is Phoenix AwardBIOS and they don't provide free updates.

Should I install the BIOS/chipset drivers from my motherboard's support page?

How can I find out more about what might be causing this or possible solutions?

- HiJackThis logs?
- LatencyMon?
- sysinternals Process Explorer?

Please help, my Java benchmarks came back at 1/4 of the speed you'd expect from a slower processor!

Comment: Look [here](http://superuser.com/questions/577008/system-acpi-sys-is-always-using-about-15-20-of-my-cpu).

Comment: Thanks, I hope it isn't the BIOS though because the one this machine has is *terrible* - wouldn't let me boot from a disk when I was trying to install a fresh OS so goodness knows how easy updating it would be.

Comment: Just realised I have been using the built-in drivers for my mouse and keyboard so installing the proprietary ones and we'll see if that makes a difference...

Comment: Keyboard/mouse drivers won't make any difference.

Comment: Do you have uTorrent installed? It can be the reason :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I decided to think a bit more hardware-related so opened to case to clean the processor heat sink. There was hardly any dust so that definitely wasn't the cause, but now System only uses around 1% of the CPU.

The heat sink must have not been fitted properly because all I did was remove it and put it back on and I didn't change anything else. Now my CPU graph actually goes down to ZERO when I'm not doing anything. Yay!

N.B. I'm an idiot.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but traced it to the DVD drive and the related system software.  First clue was when I removed a blank DVD drive from the unit, the CPU usage dropped to nil - but it came back after a reboot.  I selected the drive in explorer, right clicked on it, and was able to delete the allegedly pending files.  After a reboot the problem appears gone for good.  /Len