# How do I tell the kernel to stop trying to activate a broken USB port?

Tags: linux, usb, kernel, manjaro

### Problem

One of my USB ports (1-4) on my laptop is broken. I am not looking for a fix since it is a hardware issue, I am simply looking for a way to tell the kernel to stop trying to activate it because it is slowing down the activation of my working USB port. It also slows down reboots and shutdowns.

The kernel will try and activate the USB port even when there is no device is connected to it.

### Context

#### CPU Info

```bash
$ uname -a
Linux raphael-laptop 5.17.9-1-MANJARO #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed May 18 09:20:53 UTC 2022 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```bash
$ neofetch --stdout
OS: Manjaro Linux x86_64 
Host: HP Laptop 15-dy1xxx 
Kernel: 5.17.9-1-MANJARO 
CPU: Intel i3-1005G1 (4) @ 3.400GHz 
GPU: Intel Iris Plus Graphics G1 
Memory: 3885MiB / 7639MiB
```

Here is an example of what is happening endlessly:

```
Jun 11 10:06:44 raphael-laptop kernel: usb 1-4: device not accepting address 15, error -71
Jun 11 10:06:44 raphael-laptop kernel: usb usb1-port4: unable to enumerate USB device
Jun 11 10:06:45 raphael-laptop kernel: usb 1-4: new full-speed USB device number 16 using xhci_hcd
Jun 11 10:06:46 raphael-laptop kernel: usb 1-4: device descriptor read/64, error -71
Jun 11 10:06:46 raphael-laptop kernel: usb 1-4: device descriptor read/64, error -71
Jun 11 10:06:48 raphael-laptop kernel: usb usb1-port4: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
Jun 11 10:06:48 raphael-laptop kernel: usb usb1-port4: attempt power cycle
Jun 11 10:06:50 raphael-laptop kernel: usb usb1-port4: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
Jun 11 10:06:50 raphael-laptop kernel: usb 1-4: new full-speed USB device number 19 using xhci_hcd
Jun 11 10:06:50 raphael-laptop kernel: usb 1-4: Device not responding to setup address.
Jun 11 10:06:50 raphael-laptop kernel: usb 1-4: Device not responding to setup address.
Jun 11 10:06:50 raphael-laptop kernel: usb 1-4: device not accepting address 19, error -71
Jun 11 10:06:50 raphael-laptop kernel: usb usb1-port4: unable to enumerate USB device
Jun 11 10:06:51 raphael-laptop kernel: usb 1-4: new full-speed USB device number 20 using xhci_hcd
Jun 11 10:06:51 raphael-laptop kernel: usb 1-4: device descriptor read/64, error -71
```

lspci:

```
$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 8a02 (rev 03)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Iris Plus Graphics G1 (Ice Lake) (rev 07)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 8a03 (rev 03)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller (rev 30)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP DRAM Controller (rev 30)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 30)
00:15.1 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 30)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP Management Engine (rev 30)
00:17.0 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode] (rev 30)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 34bf (rev 30)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP LPC Controller (rev 30)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller (rev 30)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP SMBus Controller (rev 30)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP SPI Controller (rev 30)
01:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
```

Here are the `/sys/bus/usb/devices`:

```bash
$ ls -lha /sys/bus/usb/devices
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jun 11 09:37 1-0:1.0 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-0:1.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jun 11 09:37 1-10 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-10
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jun 11 09:37 1-10:1.0 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-10/1-10:1.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jun 11 09:37 1-10:1.1 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-10/1-10:1.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jun 11 09:37 1-3 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jun 11 09:37 1-3:1.0 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jun 11 09:37 1-3:1.1 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jun 11 09:37 2-0:1.0 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-0:1.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jun 11 09:37 usb1 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jun 11 09:37 usb2 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2
```

### More Information

I have attempted [bash - How to disable a specific usb port permanently in linux? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27047959/how-to-disable-a-specific-usb-port-permanently-in-linux), but the problem port does not show up in lspci and because of that I don't know what the PCI ID is.

I have tried different settings with `/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb1/power/wakeup` and `/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb1/power/control` to no avail. The only effect from the previous commands were disabling my working USB ports which is undesirable.

How do I tell the kernel to stop trying to activate USB port 1-4?

Comment: Is there something connected to that port (e.g. internal webcam) or is it detecting a ghost device? What's the output of `sudo uhubctl`?

Comment: @user1686 no, there's nothing connected to it. The output: `No compatible devices detected!`

Comment: Not an answer, but it might be related to how I fix [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1552952/acpi-sys-cpu-usage-no-solution-on-windows-but-its-solvable-in-linux) on Manjaro, through the command `echo disable > /sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe6F`.
It might be possible do disable the port through filesystem in a similar fashion.