# 100% cpu usage on both linux and windows

Tags: operating-systems

On both windows 8.1 and my kubuntu linux I get 100% cpu usage on first cpu core (core0).

In windows 8.1 it shows that acpi.sys is what causing the 100% cpu usage.
But the problem is on linux too.

Does anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: Try checking the answer to [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/577008/system-acpi-sys-is-always-using-about-15-20-of-my-cpu) and see if it helps.

Comment: Changing wake on lan didn't do anything. I'm going to try to flash bios version back to older one.

Answer (score 1):

Okay I just flashed bios back to previous version and the problem was gone.

Not sure if it was entirely the new bios that was causing the problem, or just my bios settings.

The motherboard I used was Gigabyte Z170X UD5 TH and processor i7-6700k.
The bios version I had problems with : F3

Previous Bios version: F2